# Huge fps drop when I add big image to sdl texture

Tags: c++, 2d, sdl-2, hardware-acceleration

So, there's absolutely no fps drop when i add smaller image to sdl screen, but then i added sdl background, with details and everything, on all my screen. Then i get drop from 350 to 150fps. Maybe there's a way to fix it? Add this texture to other screen or something like that ?

Here's how i add this image:

In loading of my game:

```
SDL_Texture* texture;
SDL_Rect rect;
texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "data/interiors/baznycia.png");
rect.x = 0;
rect.y = 0;
rect.w = screenWidth;
rect.h = screenHight;
```

In my game loop:

```
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &rect);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

Comment: Please check if you allow SDL to use hardware for 2D graphics acceleration. It could be that SDL is only using software rendering. https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer#flags

Comment: @nshct I use SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED, so i'm using hardware. Tried to play with those flags now, so SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED gives same fps as SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE, and others just drops to 10fps or something (when i use those, there's no counter from fraps program)

Comment: One thing I remember is that sometimes, the format of the texture (aka how the colors are laid out in memory, size of color fields...) differs from the format of your screen, so each time you want to copy something it has to be translated. You can try to copy your image into a new texture that uses the same format as your screen (you can supply that in `CreateTexture`) and try to render that to your screen each frame.

Comment: @nshct Damn! I changed my picture just to my game size, and fps boosted to 250 fps! Please write that as answer now, and I will confirm it, so other people can find fix to this problem easiely. This much fps is enough :D Thanks for help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, because you are drawing a background image of a game with constant window size, it could be beneficial to match the dimensions of your image to your screen size to avoid interpolation being applied to your texture (which takes computation time and thus might limit your FPS)

Additionally, sometimes a texture pixel format mismatch might cause unneeded texture conversions, so check that you are using the correct [format](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTexture#format) before drawing it to screen.